# Most searched words MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table which logs the search terms from every visitor. Sometimes it is a single word and sometimes it is multiple words. In my back end, I want to list the most searched words `desc limit x`.

Sure, I could do it with PHP, but I want to know if it's also possible with MySQL.

```
search_string
--------------
Hotel in Berlin
Paris
New York
Grand Hotel Principe
Royal Myconian Resort Thalasso Spa
Spa Resort
```

I know that cities like New York could be divided into New and York, but ignore this.

Thanks for help!

Comment: use fulltext search: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: 1. Open a browser, 2. navigate to google.com 3. search for mysql group by count or something 4. Write the code according to your findings

Comment: Thanks PravinS. Another question to Elias and Joshua. Do comments give reputation or why do you invest time to write useless and offensive (Elias) answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this in a single query, but you have to assume a maximum number of words.

```
select word, count(*) as cnt
from (select substring_index(substring_index(search_string, ' ', n.n), ' ', -1) as word
      from searches s cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
           ) n
      where length(replace(search_string, ' ', ' x')) - length(search_string) <= n
     ) w
group by word
order by cnt desc;
```

The nested calls to `substring_index()` return the "nth" word in your list.  The `where` clause verifies that at lesat that many words are in the list.

Comment: The amount of words is dynamic, but i will work on with your solution. Thanks